# Class diagram from a java code

Tags: java, jdeveloper

I am trying to create a class diagram using existing Java code, when I drag drop the class files to class diagram window in Jdev, it just shows empty classes ( no attributes / methods) also does not show the relationship of classes!!,,,
Please advise what could be wrong?
i did following steps -
created modelling java project with class diagram option, and then added project src files to the modelling project

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you create the class diagram in the same project that your source is in?
Does it work if you go into your UML project properties and under content add the directory where the Java source is?